# Understanding divide and conquer paradigm

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Suppose you have a 1D array A = [0...n-1]. Define a "hole" to be any position in A where all adjacent positions are greater than it. For 1D this means A [i] < A [i-1] < A [i+1] (if i is 0 then check i+1 and if i is n-1 check n-2). What divide and conquer method will solve this in the 1D case, or in the case of a square matrix? In a square matrix, (0,0) is a hole only if it's less than (0,1) and (1,0) (so corners are really corners).

I feel like I somewhat understand divide and conquer, but when it comes to applying it to problems like this I get stumped. I was asked the 1D question in an interview and failed to solve it. The interviewer told me the 2D square case was a challenging extension for practice (that hardly anyone was able to solve in full). I'm happy with psuedocode, I just really want an idea of what's going on.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525179/find-local-minimum-in-n-x-n-matrix-in-on-time

Comment: What does "solve" mean? Find a local minimum? Find all local minima?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with my logic for the divide and conquer algorithm for Closest Pair Problem‍​​?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320423/what-is-wrong-with-my-logic-for-the-divide-and-conquer-algorithm-for-closest-pai)